# WIX WixUI_InstallMode property and quotes weird behavior

Tags: wix, conditional-statements

I faced very strange behavior of WIX installer conditions, using WixUI_InstallMode property.
It behaves completely different in *conditions of  element* and in *conditions of*  elements. For example, this condition correctly leads to MaintenanceTypeDlg only when remove or repair option was used:

```
<UI>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="6"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode = "Repair" OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Remove"]]></Publish>
</UI>
```

while this one never shows the previous dialog:

```
<UI>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="6"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode = Repair OR WixUI_InstallMode = Remove]]></Publish>
</UI>
```

**The only difference is that "Repair" and "Remove" values are without quotes** in the second example. So it looks like normal and we should put values in quotes, like it is in WIX sources.

But let's consider two more examples:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="AssertUserCredentials" After="InstallValidate"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode<>"Remove"]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

**This condition is always true. So in remove mode the custom action is fired which is completely unexpected. Why is it fired?**

And again example withot quotes:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="AssertUserCredentials" After="InstallValidate"><![CDATA[WixUI_InstallMode<>Remove]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

**This now works fine without quotes and don't execute custom action in uninstall mode**.

As for me, these two usages of conditions are completely the same logic, but the behavior is completely opposite. **Can anybody explain what happens?**

Comment: Do you mean quotes ("") or brackets?

Comment: Thanks for finding that typo. Fixed it